# g++ 2.9-gnupro-98r2, error: cannot declare references to functions; use pointer to function instead

Tags: c++, g++

I am facing a compilation error with one g++ version (2.9-gnupro-98r2)for LynxOS-178B 2.2.2, whereas the same code will be compiled without complaints with a newer version of g++, e.g. 4.3.3 for VxWorks 653 2.4.0.2.

The following example illustrates the problem:

```
int method1(int);

void RefInit(){

    int (&rmethod) (int) = method1;
    rmethod(5);

    return;
}


int method1(int x){

    int y = x = 10;
    return y;
}
```

At line **int (&rmethod) (int) = method1**; for 2.9-gnupro-98r2 I am getting:

```
../../src/Overloading_13_3_1_6_Initialization_by_conversion_function_for_direct_
reference_binding.cpp(8) : error: cannot declare references to functions; use pointer to function instead
```

If one compiler version accepts the code it cannot be completely wrong. My guess is that it conforms to the C++ standard, but the older compiler was lacking a proper implementation of the same.

1. What exactly is the problem?
2. Is there a portable way of writing that kind of code such that as much compilers as possible accept it

Comment: Well the obvious solution is to do what the compiler asks you to, to use pointers to functions instead of references. Is it a possibility to do with your actual code-base?

Comment: "2.9"  and "gnupro" sound ancient. Isn't that from ~2000?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is exactly what was said in the error message.

To solve it, use a pointer to the function:

```
int method1(int);

void PtrInit(){

    int (*rmethod) (int) = &method1;
    rmethod(5);

    return;
}


int method1(int x){

    int y = x = 10;
    return y;
}
```

`rmethod(5)` automaticly converts to `(*rmethod)(5)`.

Comment: This really does not answer the question.  g++ compiles with a reference so is that okay and the OP's compiler has a bug or is it not okay and g++ is lying to him?

Comment: @NathanOliver This compiler is probably implementing the ARM at best - it's old enough to legally marry in most western countries :)